# Не подключается QMediaPlayer в Qt Creater

Tags: qt5, qtcreator

В mainwindow.h подключаю библиотеку QMediaPlayer:

```
#include <QMediaPlayer>
```

В итоге появляется красный значок и выходят данные строки:

```
ошибка: C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: QMediaPlayer: No such file or directory,
```

Как это можно исправить?

РЕШЕНИЕ В КОММЕНТАРИЯХ.

Comment: Добавьте в `pro-файл`: `QT += multimedia`

Comment: QT       += core gui multimedia - И не фига.

Comment: А обычные классы добавляются через `#include`? Возможно, вы установили версию Qt без мультимедии

Comment: Подключается все, кроме QMediaPlayer. А как ее установить?

Comment: Через установщик точно можно. Скорее всего, если его запустить, он предложит кроме установки еще и обновить компоненты Qt

Comment: Короче, я наугад потыкал, и вроде все скомпилировалось. Помогла такая штука - "Сборка/Запустить  qmake". Беспонятия что это, но оно помогло :)

Comment: С Qt чаще пользуйтесь qmake -- иногда от всякий фигни помогает пересборка с ним :)